# How to listen the listview click event in pageadapter!~

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-viewpager

I am now using viewpagerindicator which is downloaded from http://viewpagerindicator.com/. Now i can create two static page in the viewpage adapter where i can swap between 2 page. However, i cant manage how i can handle different activities in different pages. For example. page 1 is the image and i want ppl who click the image then they will start a new activity. And then page 2 is the listview. i want someone who click the list and then i can display different thing which is related to the list item. Here is the source code in the adapter. Hope anyone can help me, a big thanks and best wish for all of you. I am only a beginner....

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter

    {
        private static String[] titles = new String[]
        {
            "A",
            "B",
        };
        private final Context context;

        public ViewPagerAdapter( Context context )
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPageTitle( int position )
        {
            return titles[ position ];
        } 


        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
        {
              if (position == 0) 
              { 
                    ImageView v = new ImageView(context);  
                    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.am);              
                    ((ViewPager)pager).addView( v, 0 );
                    return v;
                }else if (position==1)
                {
                    ListView v = new ListView( context );
                    String[] from = new String[] { "str" };
                    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
                    List<Map<String, String>> items =
                        new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
                    {
                        Map<String, String> map =
                            new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put( "str", String.format( "Item %d", i + 1 ) );
                        items.add( map );
                    }
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( context, items,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to );
                    v.setAdapter( adapter );
                    ( (ViewPager) pager ).addView( v, 0 );

                    v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                              int position, long id) {


  Intent a =new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);<---(dont know how to start new activity)      
            this.startActivity(a); <-----(dont know how to start new activity, idea is to start new activity here)      

                        }
                        });
                    ((ViewPager)pager).addView( v, 0 );
                    return v;
                }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
        ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (ImageView)view );
        }else if (position == 1) 
            {
            ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (ListView)view );
            }else
            {
                ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (TextView)view );
            }

    }
```

My main is:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager =
        (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    TitlePageIndicator indicator =
        (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    indicator.setViewPager( pager );

}
```

}

Layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code is already working. Only the decision is missing, what to do on each click.

If you want to start separate Activity on each listitem, then you need a simple if-else conditional statement and start the different Activities.

If you want to use the same Activity for all (or at least some) listitems, then you have to send the position or any other information you need for the decision, like this:

```
i.putExtra("position", position);
```

Then in the other Activity you extract the information like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
position = extras.getInt("position");
```

And you can decide here what do you want to do depending on the position.

I hope this helped, if not, please be more specific, what is the difference between the desired and the achieved result.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. You are really a nice guy. My desired result is people who click the list item on page B in my apps(it is the listview in the viewpageadpter). My apps can then start a new activity and then draw a new layout.
i guess you mean what i can do is to rewrite the         
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
and then add i.putExtra("position", position); under the OnItemClickListener. Howvever, how can i start a new activity under the OnItemClickListener? Can you show the code on that part?

Comment: v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                              int position, long id) {


  Intent a =new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class); <---seems cant start a new activity with this code.......Please help!~ i want to start secondActivity.class when ppl who click the list item. I will try to handle the position problem with if cause or switch in my secondactivity.class
  

                        }
                        });

Comment: i know i can use bundle to store the id in the onclicklistener, but how can i start a new intent? My onclicklistener is in viewpage adapter instead of the mainactivity, so i wonder how can i write the intent. Please kindly show me what i can do.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried startActivity(a) instead of this.startActivity(a) ? The Activity will handle the starting of the new Activity, so you shouldn't use this here.

Comment: seems under viewpageadapter i cant start any new activity....Am i right? I check with google i found that many ppl who use intent in main activity but no one use it in viewpageadapetr. So i wonder if intent can be used in the pageadapetr

Comment: v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
              
              Intent i =new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);   
                 Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("id", (int)id);
                    i.putExtras(b);                  
              startActivity(i);

        }
        });

Comment: above not work.Anything goes wrong? startActivity is underlined by red in eclispe and it told me that "Description Resource Path Location Type
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} ViewPagerAdapter.java"

Comment: Oh, sorry. Try context.startActivity(i) .

Comment: Yes i tried. Now the code can be run without error.However, i dont know if it is really work..... Below is my code in secondActivity
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
  int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    if (value == 0) 
    { 
     this.setContentView(R.layout.text);
     TextView message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
     message.setText("abc");
   }


 }



}

Comment: When i try to compile the code and run in andorid. I click the listview. The apps is terminated automatically.....so wonder if i miss sthing here

Comment: seems does not work. When i click any item. the program is forced to be closed. Wonder if it is a must to do fragment as i am new to this. ><

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried your code. I didn't notice that the Fragments are missing. Use getItem() instead of instantiateItem().

Comment: Do you mean i must learn fragment and then use fragment to draw the layout of page "A" and "B" in my apps?

Comment: Is it possible to initiate any new activity in viewpageadapeter? Sorry i am really new in fragment and viewpageadpater, so i feel very confused.....

Comment: Yes, you will have to learn Fragments. Check out FragmentStatePagerAdapter as well:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Herrbert, i follow your instruction and then learn how to use fragment and viewpager. Everything look great now, i can create an apps like google play.However, i dont know how to start a new activity inside a fragmenet. Can you please help me again? >,,,,<

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740422/viewadapter-with-fragment-google-play-like-apps  <-----is my new question

Comment: i solve it out myself. seems i need to add manifest before i can start a new activity